# Error: invalid use of non-static data member in CPP

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to do the following:

```
class abc {
    public:
    int no_of_consumer;
    struct def {
        int p = 0;
        int c = 0;
    };
    def variable[no_of_consumer - 1];
};

int main() {
    abc obj1;
    obj1.no_of_consumer = 1;
};
```

I want the variable `no_of_consumer` to be set by the `main()` function, so that I can use this variable to define a structure array for variable `def`. But I am getting this error:

> invalid use of non-static data member "no_of_consumer".

Am I missing some concept here?

Comment: c++ does not support VLAs. `no_of_consumer` must be a compile time constant. Use std::vector for dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: Please always post the **whole** error, including the line/column number the compiler gave you.

Comment: In c++, assigning to a variable is not retroactive. Even if you could create an array data member with a sized determined by non-const like that, changing that variable could not retroactively resize the array.

Comment: OT: `no_of_consumer - 1` why -1?

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies here:

```
def variable[no_of_consumer - 1];
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In C++, array sizes must be constant expressions. If you want to have a dynamically sized array, use `std::vector` instead.

Note that you'll also need custom logic to resize your vector; as mentioned in the comments, you can't make that automatically depend on the value of your variable.

Comment: can you help me for this example. How should I use **std::vector** ?

Comment: @TusharGarg Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. Asking "How should I use `std::vector`" would be far too broad a question. Consider searching the internet for examples. Standard container templates are fundamental part of c++ and there are plenty of resources online to learn about them.

Comment: I tried using: **std::vector<def> variable[no_of_consumer - 1]**. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @TusharGarg that's expected, because you used `vector` in a wrong way. A good C++ book will explain how to use it.